# How can I check if a variable is not initialized in Swift?

Tags: swift, null, option-type

**Swift allows variables to be declared but not initialized**. How can I check if a variable is not initialized in Swift?

```
class myClass {}
var classVariable: myClass // a variable of class type - not initialized and no errors!
//if classVariable == nil {} // doesn't work - so, how can I check it?
```

Comment: Please provide your entire code, including the surrounding class definition: the code you've posted will not compile.

Comment: @andyvn22 Do you mean you get error in the third line? I've fixed the code but not checked it yet.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the last line refused to compile. Error: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'myClass' and 'NilLiteralConvertible'`

Comment: Yes! The last line does't compile - that's why I ask how can I check it!

Comment: ...If your compiler is able to get that far then you're not working with a class variable as you said you were. Is this code at the top level of a file?

Comment: @Altaveron The compiler already did the job for you. A variable cannot be nil in Swift, unless you marked it as Optional.

Comment: But I didn't initialize it. And just want to check that the class variable isn't initialized. There should be no error in the sample code - but I can recheck it only in few minutes.

Comment: All right, I've got the confusion figured out: you mean a local variable whose type happens to be a class. This question is unrelated to classes, and you should remove the `class` tag, remove the incorrect use of the term "class variable", and simplify the problem to use a built-in Swift type like Int. The compiler will have the same error when you try to compare a non-optional variable to `nil`. Writing answer now...

Comment: I've fixed noob errors in the sample code. So now it works with NO ERRORS. But the class variable isn't initialized. So, how can I check that it's not initialized?

Comment: @andyvn22 Compiler doesn't allow to have not initialized variables of built-in types but it allow to not initialize classes. So my question exactly and only about class variables.

Comment: A "class variable" is a specific programming term with a specific definition, and that definition is not "a variable whose type is a class". Read Apple's Swift iBook if you don't believe me, but you are using the term "class variable" incorrectly and it is confusing readers of your question. Last, `var uninitialized: Int`. It compiles, just like your class example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't read about 'class variables' yet. But how can I name variables of class type?

Comment: Just "variables": as I pointed out, they do not behave any differently from variables of any other type. There is no reason to refer to them differently. You can create an uninitialized `Int` just as easily: `var uninitialized: Int`. HOWEVER, whether class or not, you MUST provide a value for the variable shortly thereafter or your code will not compile. If you wish for the variable to have "no value" in a valid way at runtime, then you must declare the variable optional.

Comment: @andyvn22 You are right, thanks. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right—you may not compare a non-optional variable to `nil`. When you declare, but do not provide a value for, a non-optional variable, it is *not* set to `nil` like an optional variable is. There is no way to test for the use of an uninitialized non-optional variable at runtime, because any possibility of such use is a terrible, compiler-checked programmer error. The only code that will compile is code that guarantees every variable will be initialized before its use. If you want to be able to assign `nil` to a variable and check its value at runtime, then you must use an optional.

**Example 1: Correct Usage**

```
func pickThing(choice: Bool) {
    let variable: String //Yes, we can fail to provide a value here...

    if choice {
        variable = "Thing 1"
    } else {
        variable = "Thing 2"
    }

    print(variable) //...but this is okay because the variable is definitely set by now.
}
```

**Example 2: Compilation Error**

```
func pickThing2(choice: Bool) {
    let variable: String //Yes, we can fail to provide a value here, but...

    if choice {
        variable = "Thing 1"
    } else {
        //Uh oh, if choice is false, variable will be uninitialized...
    }

    print(variable) //...that's why there's a compilation error. Variables ALWAYS must have a value. You may assume that they always do! The compiler will catch problems like these.
}
```

**Example 3: Allowing nil**

```
func pickThing3(choice: Bool) {
    let variable: String? //Optional this time!

    if choice {
        variable = "Thing 1"
    } else {
        variable = nil //Yup, this is allowed.
    }

    print(variable) //This works fine, although if choice is false, it'll print nil.
}
```

Comment: The real situation is the following. You have class variables that may be not initialized in RUN-TIME. So you must check it before use to prevent the application to crash. How? Only to change variables to optionals?

Comment: Yes, if you are trying to allow a variable to have no value at runtime, then you MUST declare that variable as an optional. You cannot declare a non-optional variable without definitely providing an initial value for it. The ability to leave the variable uninitialized on the exact line it's declared is only so that you can provide an initial value a few lines later. The compiler will not allow you to include the variable in your code unless it is positive that a value has been provided.

Comment: But then Swift is NOT type-safe language. It seem there is a huge issue in the language conception. Not only compiler doesn't check the code to be safe - even developer (!) can't do it! Only if he use optionals instead variables in ANY case.

Comment: I repeat: "The compiler will not allow you to include the variable in your code unless it is positive that a value has been provided." That's completely safe. Please experiment and read Apple's Swift iBook from here!

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a anomaly of the compiler that you don't get an error declaring a variable this way

```
class MyClass {}
var myClass : MyClass
```

but in a Playground you get a runtime error when you just read the variable

```
myClass
```

> variable 'myClass' used before being initialized

One of the most essential features of Swift is that a non-optional variable can never be nil. If you try to access the variable you'll get a runtime error aka crash.

Comment: It's not an anomaly: it's intentionally valid to declare a variable and provide its initialization later, for example, to allow for two different initial values within different cases of a `switch`. However, the compiler will ensure that there is no possible code execution path that allows for the variable to be used before being initialized.

Comment: Yes. And I want to prevent crashes to check class variables. Why there is no way to prevent crashes with not initialized variables? It seems Swift force us to use ONLY optionals. Or you can get a crash on run-time because you can't check class variables.

Comment: Swift forces the developer to think different and to take care of those issues at design time... ;-)

Comment: If you pass a variable of class type to function compiler doesn't help you to prevent crashes!!! That's my I need to check variable if it initialized in the body of the function. And how can I do that? Only to rewrite code to use optionals instead variables?

Comment: Yes, the compiler does help you: it guarantees that unless the variable you are passing to that function is optional, it has a value. You cannot have a non-optional variable that doesn't have a value. Try it: take your `classVariable` above and pass it to a function. Compilation error. In other words, at all times in code, you may assume that non-optional variables are initialized. Always. The compiler will tell you if you forgot to initialize them.